# blackjack game for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, blackjack

I am making a blackjack game on Python for a school project. I have made the main part of my game but I keep getting a syntax error. I have tried to debug it, but I can not work out what is wrong.

Here is my code -

```
def total(hand):
    aces = hand.count(11)
    t = sum(hand)
    if t > 21 and aces > 0:
        while aces > 0 and t > 21:
            t -= 10
            aces -= 1
    return t

cards = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]
cwin = 0  
pwin = 0  

while True:
    player = []
    player.append(rc(cards))
    player.append(rc(cards))
    pbust = False  
    cbust = False  
    while True:
        tp = total(player)
        print "The player has these cards %s with a total value of %d" % (player, tp)
        if tp > 21:
            print "--> The player is busted!"
            pbust = True
            break
        elif tp == 21:
            print "\a BLACKJACK!!!"
            break
        else:
            hs = raw_input("Hit or Stand/Done (h or s): ").lower()
            if 'h' in hs:
                player.append(rc(cards))
            else:
                break
    while True:
        comp = []
        comp.append(rc(cards))
        comp.append(rc(cards))

        while True:
            tc = total(comp)                
            if tc < 18:
                comp.append(rc(cards))
            else:
                break
        print "the computer has %s for a total of %d" % (comp, tc)

        if tc > 21:
            print "--> The computer is busted!"
            cbust = True
            if pbust == False:
                print "The player wins!"
                pwin += 1
        elif tc > tp:
            print "The computer wins!"
            cwin += 1
        elif tc == tp:
            print "It's a draw!"
        elif tp > tc:
            if pbust == False:
                print "The player wins!"
                pwin += 1
            elif cbust == False:
                print "The computer wins!"
                cwin += 1
        break
    print
    print "Wins, player = %d  computer = %d" % (pwin, cwin)
    exit = raw_input("Press Enter (q to quit): ").lower()
    if 'q' in exit:
        break
print "Thanks for playing blackjack with the computer!"
```

I run 3.3.2 I have edited slightly and now get  this.

Comment: what's the syntax error?

Comment: Is this your whole code? Where is `rc` defined?

Comment: Post the traceback (the full error message).  Also post a few lines of code from before the line with the error.

Comment: I don't get a traceback just syntax error

Comment: It also gives the the line and line number of the error.  That is not always accurate because your real error can come earlier in your code, but it's a start.  We need to see that and the surrounding code to meaningfully answer your question.

Comment: Not sure about the game logic, but using `from random import choice as rc` (I guess that's what `rc` stands for) the code runs fine, no syntax errors or exceptions. What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: every time I try and run it I get "invalid syntax"

Comment: @nasher99:  I keep trying to get relevant details, but you are not providing them.  It should say more than "invalid syntax".  Also, what version of Python are you using?  Please edit your question with these details.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3 `print` is a function.  That means you must use parenthesis with `print`.

```
>>> print '?'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print '?'
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print('!')
!
```